# Should I write "two rows of wells" or "two lanes of wells" or maybe something different?

Tags: word-usage, usage, phrase-usage

I am working on a scientific paper in hydrogeology; English is not my 1st language.

The site I am working on consists of two rows (I would say) of wells in the N-S direction.

[image: sketch of two rows of well holes beside a river running north-south]

When describing the particular rows of wells, should I write "two rows" of wells? Two lanes of wells? Or?

Also, when I refer, for example, to the row closer to the river, can I write "left-hand row"? / "left-hand lane"?

I think that "row" is better because the lane is "connected" to roads?

Comment: Row is okay, but if you label the rows A and B, you don't have to lean on left-hand row.

Comment: As the rows run north-south, you can refer to the east and west row rather than right and left.

Comment: I would call them 'rows' or 'lines', not [lanes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lane).

Comment: I've come across 'a _course_ of wells', echoing a _watercourse_ and the laying out in appropriate situations of a _golf course._

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thanks, that's clever. I think I will go with this suggestion.

Comment: Have you looked up "lane" in a dictionary?

Comment: The wells are arranged in two rows.

Comment: If drilling is done according to a grid pattern, rows and lines are appropriate terms. Otherwise, you may refer to the two "wells alignments".

Answer (score 1):

You can call them [rows](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/row)

> **row**
> B1: a line of things, people, animals, etc. arranged next to each other
> *a row of houses/books/plants/people/horses*

or [lines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line).

> **line**
> C2: a group of people or things arranged in a row
> *a line of trees*

As to their location, 'left' and 'right' depend on where the viewer is standing. If you have used 'north' and 'south' you can be consistent and say

> the line of wells to the **west**... *(if the drawing has north at the top)*

or by referring to the river

> The [**riverside**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riverside) line of wells...
> The [**waterside**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/waterside) line of wells...

Even if they aren't right by the river, it is clear which row of wells is meant. Alternatively you could split those words and rephrase the sentence

> The row of wells on the river side...
> The row of wells on the water side...